# Coordinates in iTextSharp in visible CropBox

Tags: c#, itext

In iTextSharp:

Is pagesize.getTop(0) same as pagesize.Top? and similarly for other coordinates like pagesize.getLeft(0) and pagesize.Left?

See following code:

```
PdfReader PDFReader = new PdfReader("c:\\file.pdf");
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle PageSize = PDFReader.GetCropBox(1);
PageSize.Left;
PageSize.GetLeft(0);
PageSize.Top;
PageSize.GetTop(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `pagesize.GetTop(0)` same as `pagesize.Top`? and similarly for other coordinates like `pagesize.GetLeft(0)` and `pagesize.Left`?

Yes.

The methods `GetTop(float)` allows you to automatically have a margin value applied to the border, and for a margin of `0` you get the original border.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source code, they are essentially the same.
https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Rectangle.cs#L451
https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Rectangle.cs#L534

Comment: No they are not. The Get-version includes a margin.

Comment: My point still stands. The only difference is that the Get-version is using syntax sugar to add the margin as input to the border before returning the result.

Comment: The syntactic sugar is probably a result of the porting from Java to C#. The same method names obviously need to exist in the Java and the C# version and they need to work the same, and anything else is there for the benefit of the user. A bit of duplication, yeah maybe,